# Button in view doesn't call method in controller

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

i have a problem : I have a view that needs to call a method in my controller EmployeeController to go to the page to add an employee. But it don't work.. also with other views it doe

This is the view:

```
<body>
         <form class="form-horizontal" id='employeeform' id='employeeform' action="<?php echo base_url();?>EmployeeController/addEmployee" method="post">
          <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
               <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                         <tr>
                              <th>#</th>
                              <th>ID</th>
                              <th>Naam werknemer</th>
                          <th>Datum aanwerving</th>
                          <th>Salaris</th>

                     </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                     <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($employeelist); ++$i) { ?>
                          <tr>
                               <td><?php echo ($i+1); ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $employeelist[$i]->employee_no; ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $employeelist[$i]->employee_name; ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $employeelist[$i]->hired_date; ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $employeelist[$i]->salary; ?></td>
                          </tr>
                     <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
           </table>
        <input id="btn_add" name="btn_add" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add employee" />
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </form>
     </body>
```

THIS IS THE CONTROLLER:

class EmployeeController extends CI_Controller {

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    //load the employee model
    $this->load->model('employee_model');
}

//index function
function index() {
    $employeelist = $this->employee_model->get_employee_list();
    $data['employeelist'] = $employeelist;
    $this->load->view('employee/employee_add', $data);
}

function createEmployee() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('employee_no', 'Employee No', 'trim|required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('employee_name', 'Employee Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_alpha_only_space');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hired_date', 'Hired Date', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('salary', 'Salary', 'required|numeric');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //fail validation
        $this->load->view('employee/employee_add');
    } else {
        //pass validation
        $data = array(
            'employee_no' => $this->input->post('employeeno'),
            'employee_name' => $this->input->post('employeename'),
            'hired_date' => @date('Y-m-d', @strtotime($this->input->post('hireddate'))),
            'salary' => $this->input->post('salary'),
        );

        //insert the form data into database
        $this->db->insert('tbl_employee', $data);

        //display success message

        $employeeresult = $this->employee_model->get_employee_list();
        $data['employeelist'] = $employeeresult;
        //load the department_view
        $this->load->view('employee/employee_view', $data);
        redirect('employee/employee_view');
    }
}

function addEmployee() {
    $this->load->view('employee/employee_add');
    //set validation rules
}
}
?>
```

THE ERROR I GET IS :
    The requested URL /BoMaTec_afstudeerproject/CodeIgniter-3.0.1/EmployeeController/createEmployee was not found on this server.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `<?php echo base_url();?>` from the form action in the view?

Comment: why do you have two id's on your form tag?  `id='employeeform' id='employeeform'` .  Also, what does the html show as the action of the form when you view in your dev tool?

Comment: no.. i added the base url because i found on internet it's better. But without, it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have any router for that url, or the router is wrong. As per the error, it's trying to load a folder named `EmployeeController` and within that folder, another folder named `createEmployee`. Check your .htaccess file and your routers in the framework you are using.

Comment: That could be, you know what i need to add?